# Angular 8, Typescript -- How to get the list of all invalid elements in the Form after a button is clicked to display those invalid/required fields

Tags: html, angular, typescript, forms

I need to get the list of all invalid elements in the Form after a button is clicked to display those invalid/required fields.

Comment: Welcome 
Please follow this tutorial and if it did not work out ask more questions
https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/8012/angular-form-validation-example-tutorial
Happy coding !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code to console all invalid form element

```
 public invalidFormControls() { 
const invalidList = []; 
const controls = this.myForm.controls; 
for (const name in controls) { 
if(controls[name].invalid{ 
invalidList.push(name);
 } 
} 
return invalidList; 
}
```

Comment: const elements = this.myForm. elements;                                                                                                                  This gave me the collection of all the elements in the form and is working for me.

Comment: If my answer works for you, please upvote the answer.